# If $A$ commutes with $E$ then will it commute with $D$ where $E = P.D.P^{-1}$ where $P \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $E$ be an idempotent linear operator such that $E^2 = E$ .

Now $A.E = E.A$ and we see that $E$ is diagonalizable(as minimal polynomial splits) then $E = P.D.P^{-1}$ where $D$ is a diagonalizable operator. Does $A$ commute with $D$? I don't think it will but I cant't come up with a contradictory example..

Answer (score 1):

No. For instance:
$$
D=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 & 0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad P=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 1 & 0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad A=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 & 0\\0&1&1\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then $ AE=EA$ but $AD\neq DA$.

The idea is that [commuting matrices preserve each other's eigenspaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices), but if the change of basis $P$ *reorders* the basis vectors, then the eigenspaces are not equally distributed in $D$ and $E$.

Since $E$ is idempotent, its only eigenvalues may be 0 and 1. The kernel of $E$ is the first vector in the basis, which is preserved by $A$, but the kernel of $D$ is the second vector, which is not.